# Context filtering in SOLR suggester

Tags: solr

Instead of context filtering, can we add context in solr suggester response?

I have 5 different categories. Each category has different names. My suggester works on names. Can I get output as below?

```
{
  "term" : "sunnyvale labs"
  "weight":0,
  "payloads":"",
  "context":"category1"
}
```

I would also like to get something as `sunnyvale labs in category1` if possible.

Sample doc:

```
{
"key":"",
"seller_name":"",
"seller_id":"",
"partner_name":"",
"partner_id":"",
"admin_name":"",
"maintainer_name":"",
.....
}
```

Here, if user searches for a name, if any context it matches, I want to see what is the context.

Comment: Or can I get whole document where this term present?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Pherhaps you can use the payload field?

Comment: @defonion yes, that's for single field. Here the problem is that context can be on any field. let's say seller, retailer, buyer are there in different fields. How can I get that where name `James` matches?

Comment: That sounds like you need the whole document. Why dont you run a normal wildcard search query, that will return the matching docs for `James` ?

Comment: @defonion No. Wildcard search query on what field? Or condition or `dismay` parser? I have more such type of fields.

Comment: can you provide an example document?

Comment: @defonion Please check my edit.

Comment: what do you mean by context? Is it the field name the "name" is found in?

Comment: Yes I meant that. But actually I need not only the name and one more field from the doc also. Kind of matching doc.

Answer (score 0):

why don't you try defining a copyField and then use that copyField to querying.(you can source it to all other fields you think you'll require, it'll solve your problem.)